# Building a NodeJS app on Heroku deploy

Tags: node.js, heroku, build-process

What is the recommended approach to using build tools like Gulp and Browserify to build your app on deploy with Heroku? [Heroku doesn't give much info other than it's possible](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#use-npm-scripts-to-run-custom-build-steps).

The main reason I ask is because if you want to build your app on deploy you have to place your build tools in `dependencies` rather than `devDependencies`. That seems wrong to me and popular build tools like Gulp and Grunt instruct users to include them as dev dependencies so it seems like a common practice. I'm curious as to whether this is a subtle hint from Heroku to not build on deploy.

If Heroku is worried about dev dependencies polluting or compromising a production deployment `npm prune --production` can serve to prune non-production dependencies after `postinstall` scripts execute.